# inserting values into database using mysql connector python, web scraping

Tags: python, mysql, sql, web-scraping, mysql-connector-python

this code is supposed to find the first 20 headphones from the site and then get the item's name and price. Then insert them into database (into "project" table).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user="root",password='test',host='127.0.0.1',database='amirdb')
cursor=cnx.cursor()
response=requests.get(f"https://www.digikala.com/search/?q=headphone")
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

container=soup.find("ul",{'class':'c-listing__items'})
item=container.find_all("div",{'class':'c-product-box__title'})
price=container.find_all("div",{'class':'c-price__value-wrapper'})

for num in range(20):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO project VALUES(%s,%s)',(item[num].text,price[num].text))
cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```

When I want to insert them into my database(into "project"table) so it does not work and I know that the problem is in this part of my code:

```
for num in range(20):
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO project VALUES(%s,%s)',(item[num].text,price[num].text))
```

## What is the problem with this part of the code above?

The structure of the table:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| filename | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administratör/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/seventh.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO project VALUES(%s,%s)',(item[num].text,price[num].text))
  File "C:\Users\Administratör\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\Administratör\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\Administratör\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xD9\x87\xD8\xAF\xD9\x81...' for column 'filename' at row 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by database encode, modify the database encode.

```
ALTER TABLE project CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Try this.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO project VALUES(%s,%s)',(item[num].text,price[num].text))
```

If not, post the structure of your table project.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it did not work, I edited the post and put the structure of project table at the end of the post, please check it there

Comment: @amir Do you have any error messages? Please post them.

Comment: @amir I changed the answer.

Comment: I got no error but nothing is inserted into project table's values. What can be the problem?

Comment: @amir you need to commit the transaction (`cnx.commit()`)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below. I suppose it will work.

```
for container in soup.find_all(class_='c-product-box')[:20]:
    item_title = container.find(class_='c-product-box__title').get_text(strip=True)
    item_price = container.find(class_='c-price__value-wrapper').get_text(strip=True)
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO project (item_header,price_header) VALUES (%s,%s)',(item_title,item_price))

cnx.commit()
cnx.close()
```